# My JS animation resets its marginTop, but not its marginLeft

Tags: javascript, animation, positioning

Im supernew to javascript animations. I just found out how to add the 2nd movement to my animation.
When running `funk()` function, the ball goes down to the right. When it triggers `funktre()` function, the ball goes to its starting `marginTop` position but keeps its `marginLeft` position.
Why does it return to the top? I want the 2nd animation, `funktre()`, to move the ball from the `funk()`  ending position.

```
const ball = document.querySelector("#en");
ball.addEventListener("click", funk);

function funk() {
    let id = null;
    let position = 0;
    clearInterval(id);
    id = setInterval(funkto, 5);
        function funkto() {
            if (position == 450) {
                clearInterval(id);
                funktre();
                // sett en ny funksjon her
            }
            else {
                stop();
                position++;
                ball.style.marginLeft = position + "px";
                ball.style.marginTop = position + "px";
            }
        }
};

function stop() {
    ball.removeEventListener("click", funk);
};


function funktre() {
    let idd = null;
    let pos = 0;
    clearInterval(idd);
    idd = setInterval(funkfire, 5);
        function funkfire() {
            if (pos == 200) {
                clearInterval(idd);
                // ny funksjon her
            }
            else {
                pos++;
                ball.style.marginTop = pos + "px";
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*"I want the 2nd animation, funktre, to move the ball from the funk() ending position."*

Then you should not initialize its **starting position** at zero, but at its **current position**.

```
function funktre() {
    let idd = null;
    let pos = parseInt(ball.style.marginTop); // set the initial pos to current pos
    clearInterval(idd);
    idd = setInterval(funkfire, 5);
        function funkfire() {
            if (pos == 200) {
                clearInterval(idd);
                // ny funksjon her
            }
            else {
                pos++;
                ball.style.marginTop = pos + "px";
            }
        }
}
```

If you intend to program more animations, or even a video game, I would suggest storing the ball top/left position in a global variable (which you could access from any scope).

Comment: Thank you. Im not familiar with parseInt and dont fully understand it after reading it, but I got the animation working now. 
My ambition is making a super simple game, and learning more from there. Are there any good threads here about that?

Comment: parseInt will only keep the starting number, so '13px' become just 13 for example. Building a video game isn't an easy task to begin with, first you should learn the different variables' scopes to keep track of everything. Also, I recommend first writting what you want to do on paper, then start to translate it into code. (a bouncing ball call easily be drawn on paper, and help understand the math).